# How to set parameter by name instead of its position in JDBC/JPA when calling stored procedure?

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

I'm calling stored procedure from java. Now I need to set the stored procedure's parameter by its name instead of its position inidex, is it doable?

I don't want to use string concatenation though, it's not safe and ugly to deal with.

Notice: I need to work with OUT/INOUT parameters, too.

Comment: What has JPA to do with this ? using a pre-release of JPA2.1 stored procedure support? if not then which JPA implementation ? or if using JDBC then remove the JPA tag

Comment: @DataNucleus, I can choose to work with JPA or JDBC, and will chose which ever suits best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can name the parameters using the format

```
cstmt.setString("arg", name);
```

where cstmt is an `CallableStatement`

where arg is the name of the argument in the corresponding stored procedure.

We do not need to name parameters in the same order as the arguments in the stored procedure as we will use paramname in this case.

Also you can go through the Tutorial regarding the CallableStatement in the below link -

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/jdbc89.htm

You can read the link - the registerOutParameter statement is there in the link -

```
// Register out parameter which should return the product is created.
  cstmt.registerOutParameter("prod_id", Types.FLOAT);
```

Comment: But how does the setString work with OUT parameters? Or does it work at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is feasible, however not natively within the language.  You will need to write your own code to provide this functionality or rely upon a third parties code (recommended approach).  I have used the simple code from this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html) in the past with success.  It doesn't handle all cases but it is easily extendable.  The SpringFramework also provides some libraries to provide this functionality if your looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: that link is now broken